# What does "abs:%s" regex means?

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parser

I am using Jsoup in my project and i am try to get understand what these lines of code in my HTMLparser.java is step by step doing:

```
static List<LinkNode> toLinkNodeObject(LinkNode parentLink, Elements tagElements, String tag) {
    List<LinkNode> links = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Element element : tagElements) {
        if(isFragmentRef(element)){
            continue;
        }

        String absoluteRef = String.format("abs:%s", tag.contains("[") ? tag.substring(tag.indexOf("[") + 1, tag.length()) : "href");
        String url = element.attr(absoluteRef);

        if(url!=null && url.trim().length()>0) {
            LinkNode link = new LinkNode(url);
            link.setTag(element.tagName());
            link.setParentLink(parentLink);
            links.add(link);
        }
    }
    return links;
}
```

Can you tell me what "abs:%s" regex in this line is doing ?

```
 String absoluteRef = String.format("abs:%s", tag.contains("[") ? tag.substring(tag.indexOf("[") + 1, tag.length()) : "href");
```

Comment: Please quote what you found confusing in the documentation for each of those methods so we know what you have problems with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say that tag has the following value:

```
tag = "blah, blah, [medo0070";
```

then the line in question

```
String absoluteRef = String.format("abs:%s", tag.contains("[") ? tag.substring(tag.indexOf("[") + 1, tag.length()) : "href")
```

will assign

```
abs:medo0070
```

to absoluteRef because the tag variable contains the '[' character. If tag had the value

```
tag = "blah, blah, medo0070";
```

then absoluteRef would be given the value

```
abs:href
```

because the tag variable doesn't contain the '[' character.

The Ternary operator (see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) works like this:

```
a ? b : c;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (a) {
    b;
}
else {
    c;
}
```

In your example, a is *tag.contains("[")*, b is *tag.substring(tag.indexOf("[") + 1, tag.length())* and c is *"href"*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wander if you know what **indexOf("[") + 1** is do. I mean what "plus one"do to the tag. Can you tell me that ?

Comment: It's String.subString(). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)